# R basics: working with multiple variables at once and their output

Tags: r, statistics

I have a survey dataset with 40 ordered factor variables. The variables are transformed into characters when the data is imported.Please correct me if I am wrong, as I am thinking of using the `apply function` here.

Below my data manipulation:

```
### data    
v1 <- as.character(c(1,4,2,4,3,1,3,4,5,2,2,3,6,5,4,6,5,4,5,6,6,2,4,3,4,5,6,1,6,3,5,6,3,2,4,5,3,2,4,5,3,2,4))
v2 <- as.character(c(3,4,1,4,5,1,3,1,5,6,4,3,4,5,6,3,3,5,4,3,3,5,6,3,4,3,4,6,3,1,1,3,4,5,6,1,3,6,4,3,1,6,5))

df <- data.frame(v1,v2)

### transform into ordered factor

df$v1.f <- as.factor(df$v1)
df$v1.f <- ordered(df$v1.f, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

The real levels are unsorted characters, which is why I included the step. I don't mind typing this for all variables, but it seems redundant.

My second issue is with the output. I would like to create a fancy report and know how to generate the numbers for it:

```
v1.freq <- table(df$v1.f)
v1.perc <- round(prop.table(v1.freq),2)*100
v1.med <- median(df$v1)
```

How can a table that contains all the information for all the variables at once for multiple variables be printed - especially when there are no answers to a level (see `v2`, where there is no response for `level 2`; `table()` simply skips over the level).

**How do I turn the R output in a table that has the levels as headers and frequencies and percentages as rows for multiple variables?**

Copy/pasting the numbers into an Excel Sheet seems - again - unnecessary and prone to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might want to check if you have a `stringAsFactor` option for your data import function.

Then, as I understand, you want to transform your variable into ordered factors, and this for all of them. You can wrap this into a `dplyr` sentence, and use `forcats` to handle factors. Let's take your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(1:2, ~factor(.))) %>% 
  mutate(across(1:2,~ordered(.))) %>% 
  str()
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   43 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ v1: Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 1 4 2 4 3 1 3 4 5 2 ...
 $ v2: Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "1"<"3"<"4"<"5"<..: 2 3 1 3 4 1 2 1 4 5 ...
```

As you can see, the variables are transformed as ordered factors, with levels ordered alphabetically. To explain, `mutate` is to alterate your variables, `across` specify which variables you want to change, and how. Here, we want to mutate the variable `1` to `2` and apply to them the functions `factor` and then `ordered`. If the alphabetical levelling isn't the one desired, you can still mutate the column by it self and give the `levels` argument.

For the second question, as far as there is no level "2" for V2, unlike V1, you cannot merge the two variable, unless you add a level for V2 with NA. You can still check `janitor::tabyl` to give you cross frequencies, and create one table per variable:

```
library(janitor)
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(1:2, ~factor(.))) %>% 
  mutate(across(1:2,~ordered(.)))

map(df2, tabyl)
```

Output:

```
$v1
 .x[[i]]  n    percent
       1  3 0.06976744
       2  7 0.16279070
       3  8 0.18604651
       4 10 0.23255814
       5  8 0.18604651
       6  7 0.16279070

$v2
 .x[[i]]  n   percent
       1  7 0.1627907
       3 13 0.3023256
       4  9 0.2093023
       5  7 0.1627907
       6  7 0.1627907
```